# Wordpress - apply_filter that I can't connect to any add_filter

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I am trying to edit a plugin for wordpress (woocommerce) and very often I find some lines that use the `apply_filter` function, for example one is this:

```
return apply_filters ( 'woocommerce_get_variation_sale_price', $price, $this, $min_or_max, $display );
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to understand what this filter do because I can't track back where the tag is used. I scanned (with search in eclipse) the workspace without any luck, I can't find any `add_filter` with this "woocommerc_get_variation_sale_price".

How is this possible? Reading the documentation of the two functions they should be connected...

I am stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apply_filters()` function will execute any function that has been been hooked to it using `add_filter( $hook, $function_name, $priority, $num_arguments )` with the remaining values being passed to the function as arguments. This is generally how the WordPress Action and Filter hooks work to extend the functionality of core WordPress or plugins - WooCommerce in this case.

This means that the code in your example is optionally used to let you or other plugins change the value of `$price` that is being returned by the plugins. It is providing you with the parent object (`$this`) as well as other info about the variables used to calculate the price.

IF you can't find any other references to that string (**your example is missing an 'e' in the filter name**) then it means nothing is hooked to that filter and modifying the value of `$price`.

If you wanted to add a hook to filter the value of `$price` before it is returned it would look like the following.

```
// the name of the filter, the hooked function, the priority, and the # of args
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_sale_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_variation_sale_price', 10, 4 ); 
function my_woocommerce_get_variation_sale_price( $price, $product, $min_or_max, $display ){
    // Use the arguments to do whatever you want to 
    // the $price before it is returned.
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why you say that the filter name is missing an "e", I checked and (copy pasted) the line is correct and indeed I cannot find any other reference to that specific filter name. This means that each apply_filter that I see in my file is useless? So why they did put them? This is making not too much sense to me, although what you say about how add and apply work is correct...

Comment: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_variation_sale_price/
I checked also here and my theory about the fact that this hook is never effectively hooked to a function is true...